# MooTools: getChildren() on an invisble select returns an empty array in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mootools

I have some code that tries to grab the children options of a select: `$('mySelect').getChildren()`.

Sometimes the select is visible and sometimes it's not, and this doesn't seem to make a difference in Firefox, `.getChildren()` returns an array with the select options. However, I've noticed in Chrome the exact same call will return an empty array if the select is not visible.

Once the select has become visible `.getChildren()` will return the select options even if it goes invisible again.

Is there a way around this initial empty array in Chrome?

Thanks.

Edit:

My actual code for this is part of a rather large application but I tried to build a jsfiddle for with enough information for this problem, http://jsfiddle.net/6Szua/3/ , but had no luck actually reproducing the error. It would be like instead of returning 0 and an array of objects it would return -1 and [ ]. In our code, -1 falls into a special case, so the behavior was different across browsers.

If I run the debugger in Chrome's developer tools I'm able to trace the select's options being built, but once the calls finishes, it's like they were never there.

Luckily, I was able to come up with a work around for this situation, but if someone else has run across something like this before, I'd still be interested in hearing about it.

Comment: I am not seeing this behaviour. Can you post your markup and CSS / or build a jsfiddle example for it. how do you 'hide' the element, is it attached to the DOM etc? do you hide the options or the parent select?

Comment: I tried building a jsfiddle example, but was unable to reproduce the error. I posted it anyway...but for now I was able to come up with a workaround that fixes my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: In that case it probably has more to do with your code. Perhaps when you use `getChildren` there are no actual children yet (as in, there's an async call that adds the options, etc?).

Comment: did you get answer to your question? can you post the answer to your question? I didn't find anything wrong with your fiddle...